# calculation of observers latitude, first vertical

Tags: positional-astronomy

In an exercise, I have to calculate the observers latitude.
Given are the altitude a of the star at the passage through the first vertical (Azimuth = 90°/-90°), the sideral hour, the right ascension, hour angle H and declination d.

Our professor has given us two equations:

cos(a-90°) = sin(d)/sin(phi)   for |phi|>|d|
and
cos(H) = tan(d)/tan(phi)

when I use Excels atan2-function, the second equation gives me the same result as the first one, so I suppose that is the correct one?

Comment: The exercise has a lot of red herrings. You don't need to know sidereal time or right ascension. You also don't need to use any trigonometry.